# How do I write this PL/SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a table with 2 columns: Person (1), his/her friends (2).

I need a query to select all of Tom's friends, friends of his friends, friends of their friend and so on... Maybe some SQL or PL/SQL can do this?

For example for Tom this query should return: Sara, Anna, Alex, Lisa.

| Person | His/Her friends |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | Sara |
| Tom | Anna |
| Anna | Tom |
| Anna | Alex |
| Alex | Anna |
| Alex | Lisa |

Comment: It will go dead loop if you don't remove tom from middle

Comment: I don't need Tom in result. Only distinct results without Tom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query to continue from a friend to a friend or a friend and so on:

```sql
SELECT     DISTINCT friend_name
FROM       friends
WHERE      friend_name != 'Tom'
START WITH name = 'Tom'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR friend_name = name
```

**EDIT:**
To address the question in the comment about the `nocycle` option: Without any restriction, a hierarchical query could in theory recurse forever. E.g., with this data, Tome has a friend called Anna. Anna, in turn, has a friend called Tom, and without any restriction, the query could go on indefinitely between these two friends, which will cause it to fail with an "ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data" error. The `NOCYCLE` option prevents this repetition and allows the query to complete without "going back" to values it's already visited.

Comment: `NOCYCLE` should be explained ;)  *(I know plenty of people that don't understand infinite recursion in cyclic graphs.)*